# Is it possible to run NUnit tests from the main method

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit, browserstack

The purpose of this is to be able to set the project's .exe file to automatically run on startup and have the tests run. The tests are integrated into BrowserStack where I can view the results. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The NUnitLite NuGet package is a quick way to get up and running with this. Just add the package to an .exe, and it should add a template class which does this automatically.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Chris I tried to do that but I did not know how ? would you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the latest changes to the framework, it's possible to do this. Some features may not be available to you. For example, you probably will not be able to recover warning results, which don't throw an exception, or use multiple asserts for the same reason.

Most recently, before the latest release, this was broken btw, so be sure to get the latest.